# Too many instances of Log4Net LogImpl

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, log4net, windbg, heap-memory

We are using log4net to do our logging and I'm analyzing a memory-dump. We've wrapped the log4net implementation in our own class called "TextLogger" which of there are 6601 instances on the heap while there are 325882 instances of LogImpl.

This seems strange to me. We create loggers that only live for a short while so I guess its possible that they are just waiting to be garbaged collected but I still find the difference too large to be exaplained by uncleaned garbage.

Copied from windbg where first column is # of instances and second column is total size in bytes
Our wrapper-class:
6601       211232 Logging.TextLogger

log4net classes:

325882     10428224 log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.LoggerKey

325882     20856448 log4net.Core.LogImpl

325903     20857792 log4net.Repository.LoggerRepositoryConfigurationChangedEventHandler

325882     23463504 log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.DefaultLoggerFactory+LoggerImpl

Anyone experienced in log4net that would say this is normal or are we not disposing our logger-implementations properly somehow?

I guess it's also possible that we somehow hold references to the loggers preventing them from becoming garbage-collected but we dont have close to the same amount of instances of other classes that might have a reference to a logger.

EDIT:
TextLogger implementation:

```
public class TextLogger
{
    private ILog m_Logger;
    private string m_UniqueId;

    static TextLogger()
    {
        var stream = File.OpenRead(@"log4net.config");
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(stream);
    }

    public TextLogger(string name, object owner)
    {
        m_UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n").Substring(0, 6);
        if (false && owner != null)
        {
            m_Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(string.Format("{0}-{1}", m_UniqueId, name), owner.GetType());
        }
        else
        {
            m_Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(string.Format("{0}-{1}", m_UniqueId, name));
        }
    }

    public void Debug(string msg)
    {
        m_Logger.Debug(msg);
    }

    public void Error(string msg)
    {
        m_Logger.Error(msg);
    }

    public void Error(string msg, Exception exception)
    {
        m_Logger.Error($"{msg}, {exception.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br>")}");
    }
    public void Warn(string msg)
    {
        m_Logger.Warn(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share some code to get an idea of the TextLogger implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that for each instance of a TextLogger a new log4net.ILog with a unique Guid based name gets instantiated:

```
m_Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(string.Format("{0}-{1}", m_UniqueId, name));
```

The ILog retuned by log4net.LogManager stays 'alive' for the duration of your application. This makes it possible to retrieve the same ILog instance again later via its name.

Because all your instances have unique names, they count up here.

When using log4net, a typical setup is to use a static logger per component/class, as here below. Try to refactor your code into something similar.

```
class Foo
{
    private static ILog _logger = LogManager.Instance.GetLogger(typeof(Foo));

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _logger.Info("Doing something"); 
    }
}
```

This concept is well explained at the [log4net website](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, this really sounds like it would help us.

Comment: As a followup question, what advantages are there of factoring the logging into different log-instances if they al write to the same file?
Would it affect performance having just a single instance?

Comment: @taracus By including the `%logger` marker in a layout pattern, the logged message will show the class name (including namespace) from which the message originated. It also allows to configure filters like eg. log the messages of class Foo with loglevel debug (to get all details), but with loglevel error for all the others.